# JAVA_HOME error when running PIG

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, apache-pig, java-home

After I set JAVA_HOME in my environment, I got this when running PIG:

```
ubuntu@XXXXXX:~/pig/pig-0.11.1/bin$ export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun
ubuntu@ip-10-117-89-198:~/pig/pig-0.11.1/bin$ ./pig
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Permission denied
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
        at java.io.File.checkAndCreate(File.java:1704)
        at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1792)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:115)
```

When I sudo it:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-117-89-198:~/pig/pig-0.11.1/bin$ sudo ./pig
Error: JAVA_HOME is not set.
```

But in my environment, JAVA_HOME is set:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-117-89-198:~/pig/pig-0.11.1/bin$ env | grep java
OLDPWD=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun
```

Running on: Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS
Java: java version "1.6.0_21"
Hadoop version: hadoop-0.20.203
PIG version: pig-0.11.1
ENV:
    TERM=xterm
    SHELL=/bin/bash
    XDG_SESSION_COOKIE=8ae630b8b99d1e6f701be8b54f4baedf-1372165040.445642-2054865008
    SSH_CLIENT=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    OLDPWD=/home/ubuntu
    SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0
    USER=ubuntu
    LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:hl=44;37:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
    MAIL=/var/mail/ubuntu
    PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/hadoop/bin
    PWD=/home/ubuntu/pig
    JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun
    LANG=en_US.UTF-8
    SHLVL=1
    HOME=/home/ubuntu
    LOGNAME=ubuntu
    SSH_CONNECTION=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
    LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
    _=/usr/bin/env

Comment: It may not be set for sudo user. Do `sudo env | grep JAVA_HOME` to check if it is set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to modify the configuration, you can use use `sudo -E ./pig`. `-E` means passing the environment of current user to the sudo users.

Comment: Very usefull, thank you! Probably my user environment and system environment are different (---linux new user detected---).